# Sorting Collections of Collection

Tags: java

I am trying to sort file content based on the first two columns value:

My file content is:

File name : ComplexMapFileReader.txt

And the conetent is:

```
B 12 hgjhgjgjgjgjgjhgjgjgjgjgjgj
B 3 jgjdSAGdjgsdKJADJgjfgAJFL
B 6 jygtjgjgjgjgjgjhgjhbj
C 7 uiyuiyikykk
C 2 wrteyytyuiiiiyjhg
A 1 hikhkhkhkjhkhkhjkhkh
A 4 khkhkkhkhkhkhkh
A 2 khkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhh
A 11 jhgjsGJDGjAGFjgfjgjfgj
A 5 gjgjgsadgajgjDGkkhkhdDKjhkjd
B 5 hdskdhkljdhKAJHDKjahsd
A 12 kjhkdjhfknkjflkjfsdlkjf
C 3 kjhfekJEHFKHefkh
B 34 khkhkjhkjhkqlwwjljlllljj
A 21 iuhEWHRIekhrlkHRKErhwkrhk;h;kfnk.nfas
C 11 jlklkqwwlklklklllklkkkkjjj
```

> My code for the same is :

```
package CollectionExamples;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MapFileReader {

    private static final String FILENAME = "D:\\ComplexMapFileReader.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        Map<Integer, String> innerMap = null;
        Map<String, TreeMap> outerMap = new TreeMap();
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));

            try {
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    String[] s = sCurrentLine.split(" ");

                    if (!outerMap.containsKey(s[0])) {
                        innerMap = new TreeMap();
                        innerMap.put(Integer.valueOf(s[1]), s[2]);
                        outerMap.put(s[0], (TreeMap) innerMap);
                    } else {
                        innerMap.put(Integer.valueOf(s[1]), s[2]);
                        outerMap.put(s[0], (TreeMap) innerMap);
                    }

                }

                String s0 = null;
                String s1 = null;
                String s2 = null;

                for (Entry<String, TreeMap> map1 : outerMap.entrySet()) {

                    s0 = map1.getKey();

                    for (Entry<Integer, String> map2 : innerMap.entrySet()) {

                        s1 = " "+map2.getKey() + "";
                        s2 =" "+ map2.getValue();
                        System.out.println("Each line equals:" + s0 + s1 + s2);
                        System.out.println("#############");

                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The above code is not giving me the desired result. But when the above file is in some sort of ordered like (Alphabets all B's together or A's together ) then file content  as shown below gives correct sorting:

```
B 12 hgjhgjgjgjgjgjhgjgjgjgjgjgj
B 3 jgjdSAGdjgsdKJADJgjfgAJFL
B 6 jygtjgjgjgjgjgjhgjhbj
C 7 uiyuiyikykk
C 2 wrteyytyuiiiiyjhg
A 1 hikhkhkhkjhkhkhjkhkh
A 4 khkhkkhkhkhkhkh
A 2 khkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhh
A 11 jhgjsGJDGjAGFjgfjgjfgj
A 5 gjgjgsadgajgjDGkkhkhdDKjhkjd
```

And the result is the desired one (Sort by Alphabet and then by Number):

OutPut:

```
Each line equals:A 1 hikhkhkhkjhkhkhjkhkh
#############
Each line equals:A 2 khkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhh
#############
Each line equals:A 4 khkhkkhkhkhkhkh
#############
Each line equals:A 5 gjgjgsadgajgjDGkkhkhdDKjhkjd
#############
Each line equals:A 11 jhgjsGJDGjAGFjgfjgjfgj
#############
Each line equals:B 1 hikhkhkhkjhkhkhjkhkh
#############
Each line equals:B 2 khkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhh
#############
Each line equals:B 4 khkhkkhkhkhkhkh
#############
Each line equals:B 5 gjgjgsadgajgjDGkkhkhdDKjhkjd
#############
Each line equals:B 11 jhgjsGJDGjAGFjgfjgjfgj
#############
Each line equals:C 1 hikhkhkhkjhkhkhjkhkh
#############
Each line equals:C 2 khkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhh
#############
Each line equals:C 4 khkhkkhkhkhkhkh
#############
Each line equals:C 5 gjgjgsadgajgjDGkkhkhdDKjhkjd
#############
Each line equals:C 11 jhgjsGJDGjAGFjgfjgjfgj
#############
```

But when the file has the content as the below one, I am not getting the desired result. I know as it is map it will override the previous value in the below case. But is there any way better way to solve this problem.

```
B 12 hgjhgjgjgjgjgjhgjgjgjgjgjgj
    B 3 jgjdSAGdjgsdKJADJgjfgAJFL
    B 6 jygtjgjgjgjgjgjhgjhbj
    C 7 uiyuiyikykk
    C 2 wrteyytyuiiiiyjhg
    A 1 hikhkhkhkjhkhkhjkhkh
    A 4 khkhkkhkhkhkhkh
    A 2 khkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhkhh
    A 11 jhgjsGJDGjAGFjgfjgjfgj
    A 5 gjgjgsadgajgjDGkkhkhdDKjhkjd
    B 5 hdskdhkljdhKAJHDKjahsd
    A 12 kjhkdjhfknkjflkjfsdlkjf
    C 3 kjhfekJEHFKHefkh
    B 34 khkhkjhkjhkqlwwjljlllljj
    A 21 iuhEWHRIekhrlkHRKErhwkrhk;h;kfnk.nfas
    C 11 jlklkqwwlklklklllklkkkkjjj
```

Comment: With your code without changing any line of code both ComplexMapFileReader.txt gave me the same result. All sorted as expected(first by alphabets and then by number)

FYI: I used java 1.8.0_60 and I also used Jetbrain java IDE(IDEA)

Comment: Easiest way and a safer one is to create objects out of each row and save them in a collection. Then pass a desired `Comparator` to the `Collection.sort()` method for sorting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it's a better way to represent each row with a Record object. Actually we don't need the TreeMap for sorting. And it's will be much more convenient if you want to add more fields or change the compare logic. For the record list, we only need to implement the Comparable interface to implement your compare logic.

For example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MapFileReader {

    private static final String FILENAME = "D:\\ComplexMapFileReader.txt";


    private static class Record {
        private char ch;
        private int num;
        private String string;

        public void setCh(char ch) {
            this.ch = ch;
        }

        public char getCh() {
            return ch;
        }

        public void setNum(int num) {
            this.num = num;
        }

        public int getNum() {
            return num;
        }

        public String getString() {
            return string;
        }

        public void setString(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));

            List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    String[] s = sCurrentLine.split(" ");

                    if (s.length != 3) {
                        // Filter invalid records
                        continue;
                    }

                    Record r = new Record();
                    r.ch = s[0].charAt(0);
                    r.num = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
                    r.string = s[2];

                    records.add(r);
                }

                Collections.sort(records, new Comparator<Record>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Record o1, Record o2) {
                        if (o1.ch == o2.ch) {
                            return o1.num < o2.num ? -1 : (o1.num == o2.num ? 0 : 1);
                        }
                        return o1.ch < o2.ch ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                });

                for (Record record : records) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("Each line equals: %s %s %s", record.ch, record.num, record.string));
                    System.out.println("#############");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered off-topic. You must explain what you changed and why it solves the OP's problem.

Comment: It's always desirable to pass a custom `Comparator` along with sort call. So that, one is not limiting the sort functionality of `Record` objects.

Comment: Agreed with Shyam